# accumulate multiple values against one record in awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have file as

```
1|dev|Smith|78|minus  
1|ana|jhon|23|plus  
1|ana|peter|22|plus  
2|dev|dash|45|minus  
2|dev||44|plus
```

I want output as, against uniq value of column 1 and 2 print multiple values of column 3 and 5

```
1|dev|Smith|minus  
1|ana|jhon;peter|plus;plus  
2|dev|dash;|minus;plus
```

I can accumulate multiple records into 1 just for one column , I want to do it for 2 column in one command

```
awk -F"|" '{if(a[$1"|"$2])a[$1"|"$2]=a[$1"|"$2]";"$5; else
a[$1"|"$2]=$5;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' OFS="|" input.txt > output.txt
```

It is giving output as

```
2|dev|minus;plus  
1|ana|plus;plus  
1|dev|minus
```

Comment: Please edit your file data to be monospace (put four spaces before each line).  But, more importantly, StackOverflow doesn't write code or teach you how to write code, it helps you solve problems in *your* code that you cannot solve yourself.  The first step has to be yours, not ours.

Comment: It was my first post, have updated my attempts for processing

Comment: Thank you for posting your attempt.  I submitted an edit to format the code/data properly.  Please take a look at it to see how to apply this to future questions (it makes it much easier to read).

Answer (score 1):

If [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is okay

```
$ # -g 1,2 tells to group by 1st and 2nd column
$ # collapse 3 collapse 5 tells to combine those column values
$ datamash -t'|' -g 1,2 collapse 3 collapse 5 < ip.txt 
1|dev|Smith|minus
1|ana|jhon,peter|plus,plus
2|dev|dash,|minus,plus

$ # easy to change , to ; if input file doesn't contain ,
$ datamash -t'|' -g 1,2 collapse 3 collapse 5 < ip.txt | tr ',' ';'
1|dev|Smith|minus
1|ana|jhon;peter|plus;plus
2|dev|dash;|minus;plus
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk, not the usual way, but first setting `$3|$5` and then adding outwards like `<-;$3|$5;->` to `$3;$3|$5;$5`, that's why `;dash` instead of `dash;`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    a[$1 OFS $2]=$3(a[$1 OFS $2]?";"a[$1 OFS $2]";":"|")$5
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]
}' file
2|dev|;dash|minus;plus
1|ana|peter;jhon|plus;plus
1|dev|Smith|minus
```

The proper awk way would probably be closer to:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    i=$1 OFS $2
    a[i] = a[i] ( a[i]=="" || $3=="" ? "" : ";" ) $3
    b[i] = b[i] ( b[i]=="" || $5=="" ? "" : ";" ) $5
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i],b[i]
}' file
2|dev|dash|minus;plus
1|ana|jhon;peter|plus;plus
1|dev|Smith|minus
```